# How to configure AWS data pipeline using serverless.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline, serverless-framework, data-pipeline

I am new to both data pipeline and serverless. I want to know how can I automate AWS data pipeline using serverless. Below is my diagram of AWS data pipeline which exports dynamo db table to S3

[image: AWS data pipeline image]

Comment: On demand or scheduled pipelines?

Comment: @KarlLaurentiusRoos Scheduled pipelines

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure using serverless framework a right choice for this. But technically you should be able to add a [CloudFormation to create the datapipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-datapipeline-pipeline.html)  to the resources section in serverless.yml